# No wireless network after installation of elementary OS Juno

Tags: release-juno, wifi

I just installed elementary OS 5.0 Juno on an **Acer Aspire 5750Z**; nothing else is on the hard drive.

During installation, a popup indicated some "WiFi networks available" and that I could connect one after reboot using Network Manager. When I attempt to do that I don't see the WiFi network that was listed in the popup, and I am unsuccessful at adding it, with or without an Ethernet connection.

Philip Jones

Comment: Is this your WiFi device? ->Atheros AR5B97 (https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/acer-aspire-5750-laptop/5/). Could you run and output this: `$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: Here's what I get; sorry about formatting.
:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0504]
        Kernel driveer in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg3

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [105b:e040]
        Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: edit your own post, don't paste it here please

Comment: If it's solved, then mark the correct answer as accepted and if you solved by yourself, write it down and accept it. Bye

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you solve the problem, you don't have to add anything to the title.

Comment: I have also a problem with wifi. afther install 5 Juno wifi is not working. Wifi adapter is Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 PCI-E Fast Ethernet-controller (NDIS 6.30) what can a do so it is working?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after I couldn't recover from a Window's 10 bad config issue and decided to go Linux for my desktops. I even installed it three times thinking I did something wrong.  Here's the fix that solved my problem...connect to a wired interface, open up a terminal and execute

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That seems to have done the trick; thanks very much.

Comment: Dude that was what I wrote in the first lines of the answer, I can't believe it. Anyway glad you solved it but remember that this system act as a library for future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is your WiFi adapter

```
Brand: Broadcom Limited
Model: BCM43227
PCI.ID: 14e4:4358
```

First, run (to start fresh)

```
$ sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source

$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic dkms bcmwl-kernel-source

$ sudo modprobe wl
```

Reboot

If it doesn't work continue...

---

From https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

> In some computers, before performing the commands, you will need to
>   deactivate the Secure Boot Options in your BIOS. This applies for
>   cases, for example, where the bcmwl-kernel-source is already installed
>   but the driver does not yet work. You can do a reinstall like so, or
>   disable Secure Boot by going to your BIOS Setup:

After you disable `Secure Boot`, reinstall

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

$ sudo modprobe wl
```

---

If nothing above works then we have to check the modules

Just run

```
$ lsmod
$ grep -i blacklist /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:
$ cat /etc/modules
$ ls /etc/modprobe.d
```

and paste the output editing your original question please, with that info I can tell you what command to run to blacklist some modules who are in conflict

---

If `brcmsmac` and `bcma` are loaded, then...

Run:

`$ printf "# BCM43227 doesn't get detected\nblacklist brcmsmac\nblacklist bcma\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Edit `/etc/modules` (I'll use the text editor `nano`)

`$ sudo nano /etc/modules`

And remove `brcmsmac` and `bcma` from `/etc/modules`

Also if you don't have `wl` in `/etc/modules`, just add it in a new line and save the file

Reboot