# Wifi not working in elementary os elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

Tags: release-hera, wifi, networking, intel

Wifi was working fine since I installed it, the LAN ethenret had a problem, but I solved that by installing a realtek 8125 driver, that worked fine too after that.

But for some reason, after so many days, the wifi stopped working today. Bluetooth works fine. Wifi doesn't. I booted windows to check if it was my motherboard or router's fault. It works in windows seamlessly. But in elementary I don't see wireless option anymore, only wired option in network settings and the top bar.

I tried following a few things on stack exchage sites, for example [No wireless network after installation of elementary OS Juno](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17771/no-wireless-network-after-installation-of-elementary-os-juno)

But no luck, I went to the BIOS and changed it from CMS or something, to UEFI and Boot Unsecured. And I reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` multiple times without luck. Even installed a package called `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` because it said so some where on the internet, still no luck. I have no idea how to debug this either.

When I run `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       logical name: enp38s0
       version: 04
       serial: 2c:f0:5d:70:34:1e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.003.05-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:64 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff memory:f7710000-f7713fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:40 memory:f7600000-f7603fff
```

`dmesg` has as list of these errors:

```
[    4.324474] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8794:f51dd362
[    4.635086] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.636043] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636052] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-59.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636061] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-58.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636069] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636076] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636083] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636090] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636098] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636105] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636111] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636118] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.636125] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
28:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
```

Update:

Upon one answer's suggestion, I ran `sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1`, but still no luck. The `dmesg | grep iwl` output is as follows:

```
[    4.276430] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.276432] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8794:f51dd362
[    4.302977] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.303834] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-60.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.306339] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.306347] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    4.306578] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.519949] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

18/12/20202 EDIT: After a few days wifi automatically started debugging, I don't know what changed, or what update did it. I stopped installing all updates after this. Auto updates are off too. After a week or so, boom, gone again, no update installed from my side, even then.

[image: Plus I checked additional software section, it says device is not working, not sure what it means]

Plus I checked additional software section, it says device is not working, not sure what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284878/intel-wifi-ax200-msi-x570-unclaimed-driver

Disable Fast Startup on Windows 10. Works like a charm now.

This was so annoying! -_-

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `lspci` output, I can see that it looks like you have an Intel AX200 WiFi card. Hopefully this will help as an extra search term in your own research. elementary OS 6.0 Juno/Hera is based on Ubuntu 18.04, so search terms like "Ubuntu 18.04 Intel AX200" are likely to turn up relevant results.

`bcmwl-kernel-source` is a driver for Broadcom WiFi cards, not Intel ones, so this isn't relevant to your situation and can be removed/ignored.

From my research, it seems like `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` should work for your card. But there are a lot of reports about it being flaky for a lot of people. Given your `dmesg` messages about firmware issues, it might be worth trying to install the extra Linux firmware bundle first in case that helps.

You can do this with the command:

```
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

After a reboot, check `dmesg` again and see if any of the messages about firmware are different. If after this reboot, WiFi still isn't working, try removing the `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` package and rebooting and checking `dmesg` again for any differences.

Another thing, suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1169395) is to try the Ubuntu OEM kernel. Check the currently running kernel version with `uname -r`, this should probably be 5.4. You can then install the OEM kernel with:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1
```

After a reboot, running the `uname -r` command again should show you're running a different kernel version.

If you're still having issues after trying these steps, please update the original post with your `dmesg` observations after trying each stage and comment on this post.

Comment: How to revert `sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1` if needed?

Comment: Did not help, I added the dmesg output in my question

Comment: Although after running the `sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1` command and reboot, it still shows `5.4.0-53-generic` on `uname -r`

Comment: Yes, so it seems like the OEM kernel has been installed, but it isn't booted by default. In the GRUB menu when the PC boots (where you choose between elementary and Windows) there should be an option for "advanced options for elementary", you may have a choice of kernels in there. I believe the OEM version should be version 5.0. Can you see if the option to boot it exists there?

Comment: Yeah I checked the GRUB menu, and in the advanced boot options, I had the option of OEM, but inside there wired ethernet also stopped working. Even in my "normal" kernel version, I have made the ethernet work using installing realtek driver manually. But the wifi always used to work without any issues, not sure what went wrong.

Comment: In the `dmesg` output in your updated post, we can see that installing `linux-firmware` has made some improvement. It's no longer a stream of messages about firmware load failing, it actually has some messages about detecting the card. Is there anything different in `lshw -C network` when you have that more positive `dmesg` output?

Comment: Nope, it seems to be the same

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263279/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-adapter-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04 When I had started debugging this issue, before posting it here, I was getting network unclaimed like in this question, but after a few things (don't exactly know which one mattered), the unclaimed thing went away.

Comment: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Also I followed this but in vain. This was before I posted the question I think, this might have helped with network unclaimed to claimed

Comment: What is the `dmesg` output when you have `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` **removed** and still have `linux-firmware` installed?

Comment: It started working automatically one day and then a week later stopped again, I am still scratching my head :)

Comment: Finally resolved it